# Cannot post it always say the value is empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js, quasar-framework

I can't seem to figure on how to make a POST or connect to the backend (Laravel 8). I'm working on Quasar and Laravel.
I have two separate folder one on the backend and one on the frontend.

[image: Folder]

I run them both separately (Left: Laravel, Right: Quasar)

[image: CMD]

I have made the devServer in quasar proxy to get the backend.

```
 devServer: {
  https: false,
  port: 8080,
  open: true,
  proxy: {
    // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
    "/api": {
      target: "http://localhost:8080/", //tried this one also http://127.0.0.1:8000
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": ""
      }
    }
  }}
```

Here is my Vue file.

```
      <!-- Dialog  -->
  <q-dialog
    v-model="addProductForm"
    transition-show="slide-up"
    transition-hide="slide-down"
  >
    <q-card style="width: 700px; max-width: 80vw;">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Add Category</div>
      </q-card-section>
      <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-input outlined v-model="categoryName" label="Category name" />

        <div class="q-ma-md float-right">
          <q-btn label="Cancel" />
          <q-btn
            class="q-ml-md "
            label="Create"
            color="primary"
            @click="createCategory"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
  <!-- Dialog (END) -->
</q-card></q-page>
```

> 

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      addProductForm: true,
      categoryName: "Shoes",
      categories: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createCategory() {
      this.$axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createCategory", this.categoryName)
        .then(response => {
          // this.categories.unshift(response.data);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$q.notify({
            color: "negative",
            position: "top",
            message: "Unable to save category name",
            icon: "report_problem"
          });
        });
    }
  }
  // mounted() {
  //   console.log(this.categories);
  // }
};
</script>
```

and everytime I made a post. It always says that  categoryName is empty.

[image]

this is my api.php

[image]

my Category Controller.

[image]

Can anyone know how to make this work? It really says categoryName is empty.

Comment: Change this `.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createCategory", this.categoryName)` to `.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createCategory", { categoryName: this.categoryName})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a problem of axios post data format.

axios post request should contain the data part like below

> {categoryName: this.categoryName}

Comment: How can I create an environment variable for the "http://127.0.0.1:8000? so that I wouldn't have to type http://127.0.0.1:8000 over again.

Comment: add .env file in your front end project. and whenever needed in front in code use process.env.your_variable_name